# How do I use Breadth First Search to output the shortest path and not just tell me there is a path?

Tags: graph-theory, breadth-first-search

Im trying to create a program where i can add nodes and use a LinkedList to connect them. Once I have these connected nodes, I wanted to find the shortest path between them using Breadth First Search. Currently my program only finds whether of not there is a path, but i want to know what that path is. How should i modify my code?

```
public static boolean findPath(String start, String destination){
            //find the nodes given the String key
            Node current = getNode(start);
            Node end = getNode(destination);

            //create a linked list to store the visited nodes
            LinkedList<Node> nextToVisit = new LinkedList<Node>();
            HashSet<Node> visited= new HashSet<Node>();
            nextToVisit.add(current);
            while(!nextToVisit.isEmpty()){
                Node node = nextToVisit.remove();
                System.out.println(node.name);
                if(node == end)
                    return true;
                if(visited.contains(node))
                    continue;
                visited.add(node);
                for(Node children : node.adjacent){
                    nextToVisit.add(children);
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Comment: @CharlesLanglois his code does BFS with just `LinkedList` instead of `Queue`. `Linkedlist.remove()` removes the head of the list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Breadth-first will explore all nodes on all paths until you get to the destination. You would need to keep track of all the paths you're visiting until you find the right one.

Instead of only keeping the next node to visit on the queue, you could keep (singly) linked lists whose heads are the unvisited nodes, and whose tails contain the visited nodes constructing a path from the starting node. The search loop would pop a path from the queue, take a look at the head, add it to the set of visited nodes(if not already in it), then create a new path(linked list) from each neighbors, and add those to the queue. Instead of returning "True", the algorithm would return the current path when successful, or "Null" when the search fails.

However, if you're using Java(which I infer from the code), using the "LinkedList" data structure(which is a doubly linked list) would mean that constructing a new path(branching out after visiting a new node) would require copying the whole list and adding the current node's child to that new list, and adding that on the queue. This wastes lots of space and time. Sadly, Java doesn't seem to include a singly linked list implementation, which would allow sharing the tail of the list(effectively creating a tree, with each pointers on the queue pointing to the leafs of that tree) and would be much more memory and time efficient.

So to implement that solution, you would need to either implement a singly linked list yourself, or use a library which provide an implementation. Implementing it yourself is not too hard, as it's a very simple data structure, and there are lots of resources and exemples for that(beginning with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list#Singly_linked_list)).

For the latter solution, look at [functionaljava](http://www.functionaljava.org/)([list interface](http://www.functionaljava.org/javadoc/4.7/functionaljava/fj/data/List.html)) or [vavr](http://www.vavr.io/)([list interface](http://static.javadoc.io/io.vavr/vavr/0.9.0/io/vavr/collection/List.html)).

Here's what the code would look like, using the syntax of the vavr library for the singly linked lists:

```
public static List<Node> findPath(String start, String destination){
        //find the nodes given the String key
        Node current = getNode(start);
        Node end = getNode(destination);

        //create a linked list to store the visited nodes
        LinkedList<List<Node>> nextToVisit = new LinkedList<List<Node>>();
        HashSet<Node> visited= new HashSet<Node>();
        List<Node> currentPath = List.of(current);
        nextToVisit.add(currentPath);
        while(!nextToVisit.isEmpty()){
            List<Node> path = nextToVisit.remove();
            //get the "head" of current path, which is the unvisited node
            Node node = path.peek();
            System.out.println(node.name);
            if(node == end)
                return path;//return current path
            if(visited.contains(node))//this path doesn't lead anywhere
                continue;
            visited.add(node);
            for(Node children : node.adjacent){
                nextToVisit.add(path.prepend(children));//adding new path
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Note that if you only want to know the path(i.e. print the name of the nodes on that path), and not have an actual reference to that path, just iterate over the list and print each node before returning:

```
public static boolean findPath(String start, String destination){
        //find the nodes given the String key
        Node current = getNode(start);
        Node end = getNode(destination);

        //create a linked list to store the visited nodes
        LinkedList<List<Node>> nextToVisit = new LinkedList<List<Node>>();
        HashSet<Node> visited= new HashSet<Node>();
        List<Node> currentPath = List.of(current);
        nextToVisit.add(currentPath);
        while(!nextToVisit.isEmpty()){
            List<Node> path = nextToVisit.remove();
            //get the "head" of current path, which is the unvisited node
            Node node = path.peek();
            System.out.println(node.name);
            if(node == end){
                System.out.println("The path:");
                for(Node n: path)
                    System.out.println(n.name);
                return true;//return current path
            }
            if(visited.contains(node))//this path doesn't lead anywhere
                continue;
            visited.add(node);
            for(Node children : node.adjacent){
                nextToVisit.add(path.prepend(children));//adding new path
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.com, Although this sounds like a homework question, I will try to guide you through the solution rather than giving you the coding solution.

If you have a connected graph, BFS works by traversing the closest unvisited nodes, this feature allows you to reach a certain nodes at its closest.

For the shortest path, What I usually do is for each visited node, I keep the previous node that I came from. Once I have reach my destination, I would backtrack the path that I came from, and reverse that path to put it in the correct orientation.

Comment: In a graph, keeping the previous node doesn't help backtracking all the way back to the starting node. You need to keep track of all previous nodes on the path.

Comment: @CharlesLanglois Yes That's what I meant, sorry if I didn't make it clear.

Answer (score -1):

Just print the visited node as soon as you push it in the hash set..
The path would be printed..

After **

> visited.add(node)

**
Print the value of node